# Numerical Obscurification

Tags: vba, long-integer, security-by-obscurity

Similar to this question in C#: [User ID obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755713/user-id-obfuscation)

I'm looking for a solution in `VBA` to obscure a long value through an *encoding* method and also I would need to be able to *decode* the number produced as well.

Comment: why not use a guid? also, in what context are you doing this? surely you can't be writing web apps in VBA?!?!?!

Comment: Check this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8047094/5090027 While it doesn't have an accepted answer, there are many views presented and it seems to have just been abandoned by the OP.

Comment: @Jeremy No not for a web app! Couldn't thing of a worse language to use! I'm looking to obscure an (already in place) id field which is an integer hence Going to struggle to move to a guid.

Comment: @Gareth in what type of app? excel? access?

Comment: @Jeremy Excel sorry.

Comment: and where are you showing this ID? in a sheet? in a vba form? why show it, can it just be hidden, especially if it's in a column.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer as stated on the referenced article: [User ID obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755713/user-id-obfuscation)

Why not add a GUID and a lookup table?

Comment: As per comment above, it's an existing table with integer id's in it that I'm looking to obscure.

Comment: I think the question is too broad to answer - if you assume that the table could hold MAX_INT and that you could have MAX_INT values in the table, then all you can do is map 1 value to another value.  If you have MAX_INT values, there is no formula you can use where someone could enter a number that doesn't match something.  To put that another way, if you can store 10 values, the most you can do is map each value to a different number - but 1 - 10 will always produce a valid hit on some form of data.

Comment: How can it be too broad if it can't be answered?

Comment: You never said what type of data it is, or how much of it you have.  If it's a user id and you have 10 users in the system and only ever expect to get 20 users, you can obscure it with a formula that distributes the values of say 100 across MAX_INT.  So is MAX_INT was 1MM, and you had a max of 100 users, you could multiply the values by 10K.  If an even distribution of 1 every 10K.  This may be exactly what you're looking for, or it could be way too "weak" an obfuscation.

Comment: There are a lot of variables about what you're trying to do and how much space you have to work with and what happens if there's a wrong hit, to fully answer your question.

Comment: Sorry might have been a bit brash yesterday. By `Long` in the op, I was referencing VBA's 32 bit signed integer. Essentially, the `Id` serves as a reference on a system to the end user.